# Extension for aws_lambda in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dockerfile

I am receiving the following error when trying to create the Postgres extension 'aws_lambda':

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/aws_lambda.control": No such file or directory

So I realised that the extension control file needs adding but where do I find it. I am deploying the DB in a Docker container but the migration is not working as per the above error.